# Is there a better way to solve the problem of city linked by roads?

Tags: c, logic

I have been working on a problem I solved but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it.
I m working in windows 10 with visual studio. I know I'm using a c++ compiler but the code needs to be in C.

The problem:
On mars surface there are N city connected by M roads, humans want to destroy roads, but only strategic roads. A road is strategic if and only if without that road a pair of cities is no longer connected. Because humans are going to destroy some roads they are constructing Q new road.

Input:
a .txt file, on the first line there are 3 number N, M, Q, the following M line are the link on mars surface, the next Q lines contains the roads martians are going to build.

input.txt

```
5 4 2
5 1
3 2
2 5
4 2
1 2
5 3
```

Output:
Q line which contain the number of strategic roads after adding each line.

output example:

```
2
1
```

I tought to create a dynamic array and add a city if it is connected with another city in the array, if at the the end of the loop 2 city are not in the array the road which links those two city is not strategic.

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define MAX_LINKS (250000)

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} link_t;

int N, M, Q, L, i;
link_t links[MAX_LINKS];

int find(int, int*, int);
bool strategic(link_t);

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    assert(scanf("%d%d%d", &N, &M, &Q)==3);
    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        assert(scanf("%d%d", &links[i].a, &links[i].b)==2);
        ++L;
    }
    int strategic_roads;
    for (i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
        assert(scanf("%d%d", &links[M + i].a, &links[M + i].b) == 2);
        ++L;
        strategic_roads = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < L; ++j) {
            if (strategic(links[j])) {
                ++strategic_roads;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", strategic_roads);
    }
}

int find(int val, int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == val) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

bool strategic(link_t link) {
    int counter = 1, size = 1, *arr;
    int find_a = 0, find_b = 0;
    arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = link.a;
    bool still_working;
    do {
        still_working = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < L; ++i) {

            if ((links[i].a == link.a && links[i].b == link.b) || (links[i].a == link.b && links[i].b == link.a)) {
                continue;
            }

            find_a = find(links[i].a, arr, size);
            find_b = find(links[i].b, arr, size);

            if (find_a < 0 && find_b >= 0) {
                ++size;
                arr = (int*) realloc(arr, size * sizeof(int));
                arr[counter] = links[i].a;
                ++counter;
                still_working = true;
            }

            else if (find_a >= 0 && find_b < 0) {
                ++size;
                arr = (int*)realloc(arr, size * sizeof(int));
                arr[counter] = links[i].b;
                ++counter;
                still_working = true;
            }

        }
    } while (still_working);
    return (find(link.b, arr, size) < 0);
}
```

Do you know another better way to solve it?

Comment: _Side note_: Better to use `fopen/fscanf` than `freopen/scanf`

Comment: You should not use `assert` to validate user input. Only use `assert` on things you control.

Comment: Also, if you create a non-debug build with `NDEBUG` defined, then the whole contents of the `assert` macro will never be executed, so the entire `scanf` statement will be removed. You should never call important code inside the `assert` macro. It should only contain code that is used purely for verification, and can be removed safely without changing the behavior of the program.

Comment: A general rule for this kind of programming question. Dont play with any dynamic allocations. The are slow and error prone. Use large static arrays dedicated for worst case scenario defined by the problem's limits. Always assume that this worst case will eventually appear. There is no point in saving memory.

Comment: Can it be assumed that initially all cities are connected? Otherwise all roads would be technically strategic.